# Getting 401 unauthorized error in Report Viewer Control in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

```
protected void bnt_click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportViewer1.Width = 800;
    ReportViewer1.Height = 600;
    ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
    IReportServerCredentials irsc = new CustomReportCredentials("username", "password", "someserver:8080/Reports"); // e.g.: ("demo-001", "123456789", "ifc")
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://someserver:8080/ReportServer");
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Masha/Returns"; //e.g.: /demo-001/test
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
}

public class CustomReportCredentials : IReportServerCredentials
{
    private string _UserName;
    private string _PassWord;
    private string _DomainName;

    public CustomReportCredentials(string UserName, string PassWord, string DomainName)
    {
        _UserName = UserName;
        _PassWord = PassWord;
        _DomainName = DomainName;
    }

    public System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
    {
        get { return new NetworkCredential(_UserName, _PassWord, _DomainName); }
    }

    public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie, out string user,
     out string password, out string authority)
    {
        authCookie = null;
        user = password = authority = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am trying to embed SSRS report viewer in m ASP.Net Project. I am trying to connect to a remote SSRS report server displaying a report in Report viewer. For the authentication part, I am getting this:

> 401 unauthorized error

How to remove authentication or bypass it?

I can access the report server through web browser by using the login credentials.